# Using the widget, I used the CheckboxSelectMultiple field, as a result, the queryset returns None

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I put a form in the template and implemented the addition of an article. As a result, the user fills in the information, especially the categories that are used in multiple relationships and clicks submit. The information can be saved. Here, it is important that the user clicks on one of the categories. Everything, but as a result, the article with correct information but the categories returns None, this is my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1kCH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNPD.png)

models.py

```
class CategoryArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='عنوان')
    url_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='عنوان در url')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='فعال / غیرفعال')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url_title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'دسته بندی مقاله'
        verbose_name_plural = 'دسته بندی های مقاله'


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='عنوان مقاله')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='اسلاگ')
    article_category = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryArticle, verbose_name='دسته بندی مقاله')
    short_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='توضیح مختصر')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='نویسنده')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='تاریخ ایجاد مقاله')
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='تعداد بازدید', editable=False)
    preview_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/previews_articles/', verbose_name='پیش نمایش مقاله')
    content = CKEditor5Field('Text', config_name='extends')
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_files/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='فایل صوتی',
                                  validators=[validate_audio_file])
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='فایل ویدیویی',
                                  validators=[validate_videos_file])
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='فعال / غیرفعال')
    is_important_new = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='اخبار مهم')
    is_special = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='ویژه')
```

forms.py

```
class CreateArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label="دسته بندی مقاله",
        queryset=CategoryArticle.objects.filter(is_active=True),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["content"].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'categories', 'short_description', 'preview_image', 'content', 'audio_file',
                  'video_file', 'is_active', 'is_important_new', 'is_special']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'short_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 3}),
            'preview_image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'audio_file': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'video_file': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_active': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'is_important_new': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
            'is_special': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
class CreateArticleView(View):
    def get(self, request: HttpRequest):
        form_article = CreateArticleForm()
        context = {'form': form_article}
        return render(request, 'author_module/add_article_author.html', context)

    def post(self, request: HttpRequest):
        form_article = CreateArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_article.is_valid():
            article = form_article.save(commit=False)
            article.author = request.user
            article.save()
            messages.success(request, 'مقاله شما پس از تصویب توسط مدیریت، به وبسایت منتقل خواهد شد.')
        else:
            for field, errors in form_article.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    messages.error(request, f"{field}: {error}")
        context = {'form': form_article}
        return render(request, 'author_module/add_article_author.html', context)
```

---